# How do I change the refresh rate of my second monitor in Fedora?

Tags: refresh, fedora, monitor, rate

I'm running Fedora 28 Workstation and I've attached my brand new Asus MG279Q monitor to it. By all accounts, the refresh rate of my monitor is 60Hz, even though it technically supports a refresh rate of up to 144Hz. My display settings in Fedora do not let me change the refresh rate at all. To complicate matters further, I have an Asus N550JV laptop which has two video cards in it.

I've done some searching online, and I've found a bit of information on the subject but it's a bit over my head which is why I've come here. Is it possible to up the refresh rate of my secondary monitor? If so, how? And please, be as specific as possible since I'm somewhat of a beginner with Linux.

Thanks!